# Appending Select LINQ lambda expression to existing general expression

Tags: c#, linq, azure

I am wantto solve the problem where in Azure table storage Count is not currently available as of now March 2014. So, I read that adding Select to the get all items will speed up the query. So, I want to intercept the chain in my repository layer and add the Linq Lambda expression to the incoming expression:

```
public int Count(Expression<Func<TDomainObject, bool>> filter)
   {
      //here I want to append a Select expression to the filter. How to do that

      return GetBaseQuery(filter, null).Count(); //it will call TableStorage class
    }
```

I have tried something like this, but is wrong.

```
 Expression<Func<TDomainObject, bool>> selectPartitionKey = Expression.Lambda(Select(x=>x)); //Error cant resolve Select
    Expression<Func<TDomainObject, bool>> newQuery = 
      filter.AndAlso(filter,selectPartitionKey//Error: Cannot convert binary expression to Expression<Func<TDomainObject, bool>> type
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can't append a `Select` to the `Where` filter logic. Can you show us `GetBaseQuery`? That might be the place to add something. Basically, right now you have `something.Where(filter)`, and you need `something.Where(filter).Select(someSelect)`.

Comment: Yes, this exactly what I need. I do not want/cant to change GetBaseQuery. I can add the select in each Domain Repo, but this is not what I wanted.